# django-allauth: user registration via email confirmation

Tags: python, django

i am using django-allauth for user registration and i would like the users to confirm their emails

Right now, im getting the following error because my web server does not allow emails via port 550

```
SMTPSenderRefused at /accounts/password/reset/
(550, '5.0.0 Access denied', u'webmaster@localhost')
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://<mysite>.com/accounts/password/reset/
Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: SMTPSenderRefused
Exception Value:    
(550, '5.0.0 Access denied', u'webmaster@localhost')
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py in sendmail, line 731
Python Executable:  /home/public/env/bin/python2.7
```

i've contacted my web hosting people they said they only allow outbound email by /usr/bin/sendmail executable

is there way to modify django-allauth so that the email mechanism uses sendmail executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example settings for sending through Gmail:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'you_password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: Django Version: 1.9
Exception Type: SMTPAuthenticationError
Exception Value: 
(534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbuW\n5.7.14 Ue2lz0dhl4d2TLfqylq71-JsqH2w37_gPos8loMh-lU9Ql_Ycf2zywHvyZRzGzF83-7hJr\n5.7.14 tJhGItcgym_s7ID2wOCcweH3gcDgH1FsO9soaSlQq7b2kbnQfdFoNND7mWbf64es6Isj83\n5.7.14 cuwTOOkCcJk7lhn41UoIUgrzuGZVbmXAKVeOVAx2w-s2uExnlBiP7hkcpZyrgZNkruc3Iw\n5.7.14 UlMjyQbIf_JUx618jotyFof1C5G_w> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 l88sm2381107pfj.7 -

Comment: it work after going into google account and turn on "less secure app" thanks!

Comment: Yes, for new Google account must be unlock by: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps  OR https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha